# Sorting a list of Topics based on the created_at date of their last post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Making a forum app.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :posts, :inverse_of => :topic
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic, :inverse_of => :posts
end
```

When viewing a Board, I want the list of Topics to be in the order of the Topics last post created_at date. But, I cannot figure out how to write this in a way that can be understood by the order() method.

Ideally, it would be simple like this

`@topics = @board.topics.order("topic.posts.last.created_at")`

Anything I write returns errors about the column not existing.

One important thing to note is that this `@topics` will be fed into paginate, so I can't simply extract the results of `@board.topics`, order them myself and then paginate due to paginate requiring a specific type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always attach the error message.
2. use sort:

   `@topics = @board.topics.sort{|t| t.posts.last.created_at`}

Comment: Your method returned an error: `CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = ? ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["topic_id", 3]]
*** ArgumentError Exception: comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with 0 failed`

Also, I have already attempted something like this and it did not work because, once sorted, paginating on the resulting sorted list results in the following error: `*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0xb571f63c>`.

Comment: due to this error try adding require `'will_paginate/array'` in your controller